# Hide/Show UIImage on UIbutton When Clicked

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uibutton, uiimage

I have 10 UIimages and 10 UIButtons. M assigning Images to buttons via array.

I want my to hide and show the images only on button Click.

Is there any way to hide and show the UIImage whisch is assigned to button via array?????

Comment: you need to post some code.What you can do is take one transparent image and when you want to hide that image set that transparent image to that particular button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign for every UIImage and UIButton the same Tag by setTag proprieties then when you click on a specific UIButton search the array and tag the tag that related to the selected UIButton, Then use the retrieve tag to retrieve the UIImage and use the proprieties setHidden TO Hide/Show it.

and surely you have to use UIImageView instead of UIImage.